# How to change date format to strtotime in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to convert date format to strtotime in codeigniter to cross check the expire date from the database.

My code look like this below

```
$expiredate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($tra->t_started)). '+30days'));
                     
if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) > strtotime($expiredate)){
    $ra->is_paid="1";
    //package is expired for 30days.
} else{
    $ra->is_paid="0";
    //package is expired for 30days.
}
```

I need help to solve this problems. Thanks

Comment: Solve WHAT PROBLEM

Comment: Start by showing us what is in `$tra->t_started`

Comment: foreach($result_tra as $tra){
    
  $expiredate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($tra->t_started)). '+30days'));
     
  }

Comment: @RiggsFolly, strtotime is not working on codeigniter

Comment: I beg to differ. I use strtotime literally every day on codeigniter and it works just fine. That said, to add 30 days you should use `+30 day` not `+30 days`

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here:

First, you don't need to convert dates with `strtotime` to compare them.

Second, to add a certain amount of days to a date, you use `+30 day` (singular) not `+30 days`

You could simply:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($tra->t_started."+30 day"));

 if ($now >= $expire_date)
 {
      // 30 or more days overdue
 }

 else
 {
      // Less than 30 days overdue
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this worked for you, it'd be great to get your upvote :)

Comment: $tra->t_started = NULL, go to else condition.